# Photoswipe multimedia gallery with caption

Tags: html, caption, photoswipe

Good morning to everyone,
After a series of attempts and research I was able to find this example that definitively solves the possibility of creating a multimedia gallery (images, selfhosted or not videos, iframe and so on).
https://codepen.io/makshh/pen/ONMVMm
It's based on photoswipe then I should insert a description in the image. I read the documentation and inserted the  tag correctly but it's previewed below the thumbnail and not in the slider.
Eg:

```
<div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="photoswipe-item">
          <a href="https://www.w3schools.com/css/img_fjords.jpg">
            <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/css/img_fjords.jpg" alt="Image description" class="img-responsive">
          </a>
<figcaption>dummy description</figcaption>
        </div>
      </div>
```

At this point I tried to encapsulate (as per documentation https://photoswipe.com/documentation/getting-started.html) the image in the  tag but nothing to do.
Do you have any idea how to correctly insert the caption for each image / video?
Thank You in advance anyone who can help me
Regards
Ale

Comment: I recommend looking for an alternative, such as https://fancyapps.com/docs/ui/fancybox/

Comment: Good morning Janis. I solved using Light Gallery. https://www.lightgalleryjs.com/
May be could be useful for someone.
Thank You fore reply and support.
Warm regards
Ale